# vertical-align breaks text-underline

Tags: html, css

I set a vertical align to be centered with my profile image. On my end the vertical align is perfect with the profile image. The issue is that the underline text breaks on the left of Tom. How can i have my vertical-align set to middle and have the text not break on the left of the word Tom?

http://jsfiddle.net/5zrxd9c1/1/

```
<a href="/user/tomjones" class="image" title="View profile">
   <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a9/Macaca_sinica_-_01.jpg/220px-Macaca_sinica_-_01.jpgn" class="gravatar" width="28" height="28" style="border-radius: 50px; padding:2px;border: 2px solid #fff;" alt="">
    <span style="height: 33px;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;/* ext-underline-position: inherit; *//* margin-top: -5px; */" class="username">
      Tom Jones
    </span>
</a>
```

CSS:

```
   .username {
      height: 33px;
      display: table-cell;
      vertical-align: middle;
    }
    body {
      background-color:powderblue;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you to style the a tag:

```
a{
 text-decoration: none;
 }
```

And if you want the underline:

```
.username {
height: 33px;
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
text-decoration: underline;   
}
```

Take a look in [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5zrxd9c1/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Here http://jsfiddle.net/5zrxd9c1/4/
Check out the answer exactly like what you want

```css
a{
     white-space:nowrap;
}
    .username {
    display: table-cell;
    width:1%;
 
}
body {
  background-color:powderblue;
}
```

```html
<a href="/user/tomjones" class="image" title="View profile">
                  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a9/Macaca_sinica_-_01.jpg/220px-Macaca_sinica_-_01.jpgn" class="gravatar" width="28" height="28" style="border-radius: 50px; padding:2px;border: 2px solid #fff;" alt=""><span class="username">Tom Jones</span>
                </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.username {
    height: 100px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    }
body {
  background-color:powderblue;
}
```

```html
        <a href="/user/tomjones" class="username" title="View profile">
                  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a9/Macaca_sinica_-_01.jpg/220px-Macaca_sinica_-_01.jpgn" class="gravatar" width="28" height="28" style="border-radius: 50px; padding:2px;border: 2px solid #fff;" alt="">
                  <span >Tom Jones</span>
                </a>
```

[image]

Try this code, with minor changes it works but for some reason not showing correctly in this editor. On the other hand, you can use text-underline:none on the  tag for totally not showing the line.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this

Click here
https://jsfiddle.net/kblau237/sdc28tg7/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Tut124</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .username {
            height: 33px;
            /*!!! removed this*/
            /*display: table-cell;*/
            /*vertical-align: middle;*/
            /*!!!added these*/
            position: absolute;
            left: 50px;
            top: 18px;
        }

        body {
            background-color: powderblue;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="/user/tomjones" class="image" title="View profile">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a9/Macaca_sinica_-_01.jpg/220px-Macaca_sinica_-_01.jpgn"
             class="gravatar" width="28" height="28" style="border-radius: 50px; padding:2px;border: 2px solid #fff;"
             alt="">
        @*!!!Changed the display to table-row   removed vertical-align: middle;*@
        <span style="height: 33px;display: table-row;text-decoration:underline" class="username">Tom Jones</span>
    </a>
</body>
</html>
```